# programs not showing anymore on the left of the screen

Tags: menu

I had installed VLC, which was showing on left-hand side of the screen, but after a reboot I don't see it anymore, as is the case with gparted, which I alsoinstalled to be able to change a label of a partition

Answer (score 0):

Have you pinned VLC to the unity launcher (the left side panel)? Or gparted? When the program is open, right click it and select pin or add to dock or something. To open gparted or VLC use the unity launcher. Good luck!

Comment: The option is lock to launcher.

Comment: how do I start the unity launcher

Comment: It's the icon at the top of the unity bar on the left. The Ubuntu logo. Click that or press the windows button on your keyboard and search for VLC. Open VLC then lock that. After, open Gparted and lock that.

Comment: but then I still am not able to start programs that are installed like vlc and gparted

Comment: The VLC Media player should appear on your Unity launcher after starting it via the dash home on the top of the unity launcher. Same with Gparted. Remember to right click VLC once it's on the launcher and lock it. Also remember to do that with Gparted.

Comment: sorry, but when I right-click on vlc I don't get a lock option ...

Comment: HI, I think I have now got what i wanted, thanks for the help.